# Values aren't writing into cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value that is being returned from my index and match commands (workOrder in my code), but when I try to write this onto my dashboard, I keep getting this error:

[image]

I currently have this written out:

```
                        Dim Row As Integer
                        Dim WorkOrderColumn As Integer
                      
                        Row = 17
                        WorkOrderColumn = 5
                        Debug.Print workOrder
                        
                        .Cells(Row, WorkOrderColumn).Value = workOrder
```

This is how workOrder is being returned

```
        workOrder = Application.Index(WorkOrderRange, Application.Match(cel, DeliverableDateRange, 0))
```

Comment: This is working only from the shown code but removing the period in front of Cells(... should solve the problem.

Comment: ha! that works!